# Onclick not triggered in elements inserted to DOM

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dynamic, onclick, load

Onclick event of dynamic button (button which is loaded to DOM after page load) will not trigger in some specific instances of IE. Problem can be invoked especially on server windows in IE. It is not dependent on IE version.

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').append('<input type="button" onclick="alert(1);" value="Test"/>');
});
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbzu7xkz/4/

I know there are alternatives to bind onclick another way, but unfortunatelly in my case it is not possible.

- Is there some workaround I can do when I load the button to page, like calling some initialization or so ?
- Is somewhere problem described with possible solutions?
- Could it be solved by patching or reconfiguring IE ?

Any help appriciated.

Comment: What do you mean it's not possible? Are you not able to edit the JavaScript that creates the button?

Comment: The above code works fine in ie9

Comment: Whole system is based on onclick attributes inside tags. Buttons are actually loaded to DOM with other HTML elements via AJAX.

Comment: For example:
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
IE 11 V 11.0.9600.17107
Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically added elements with inline JS events will not trigger in this case. Please use jQuery's

```
.on( "click", handler ) //or a shortcut .click()
```

A nasty workaround would be to attach the event in case it's not being binded in those specific cases:

```
var wrapper = $('#test');

wrapper.append('<input type="button" onclick="alert(1);" value="Test 2"/>');

//if click event isn't presented
if (typeof(wrapper.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick) === 'undefined'){
    // let's attach the event
    $('#test>input[type="button"]').click(function(){
        var js = $(this).attr('onclick');
        // and evaluate your JS
        eval(js);
    });
}
```

If course, ideally, this shouldn't happen. All events should be binded dynamically in JS.

This fiddle is tested on older IE and works just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbzu7xkz/5/

Comment: Thanks, I noticed you have updated my fiddle with solution http://jsfiddle.net/sbzu7xkz/5/ which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Older browser have some trouble with `HTML Singleton Tags`. Try using "correct"/old HTML.

```
    $('#test').append('<input type="button" onclick="alert(1);" value="Test"></input>');
```

IE will only append items that use correct html (and IE wants closed html tags)

Comment: Unfortunatelly button still not triggers onclick after change.